# Can you find the closed form of the following infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let $F_1(y)$ and $F_2(y)$ be two functions of $y$. We define the followings:
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&z_0=F_2(y),\\
&&z_1=F_1(y)z_0'+F_1'(y)z_0,\\
&&z_2=F_1(y)z_1'+F_1'(y)z_1,\\
&&z_3=F_1(y)z_2'+F_1'(y)z_2,\\
&&...~~...~~...,\\
&&z_n=F_1(y)z_{n-1}'+F_1'(y)z_{n-1},~~n=1,...\infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
and $\epsilon$ is a parameter. Then compute the value of the infinite series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon^nz_n}{n!}$$.

Here $'$ denotes derivative.

Comment: What have you tried?  Does it help to note that $z_{n+1} = (F_1(y) \cdot z_n)'$?  I'm assuming you're taking derivatives with respect to $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, derivatives are with respect to y. Yes, z_{n+1} can be expressed in the above form. But still, I could not express the series in closed form. Any kind of help and suggestions are welcome.